# OpenJDK 10 rejects all SSL certificates

Tags: java, ssl

I installed OpenJDK 10. What I did was just unpack it, set the PATH variable and the JAVA_HOME variable.

Java even rejects the certificate of google.de (and all others I tried). I tested this by some dummy class that tries to connect. Outcome is:

```
C:\Users\Alexander\Downloads>java SSLPoke google.de 443
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:343)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:226)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:133)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1947)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1777)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1098)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processRecord(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.processInputRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1137)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1074)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:733)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:67)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:81)
        at SSLPoke.main(SSLPoke.java:31)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
        ... 18 more
```

Found a lot on the net how to add special certs to java but i think in my java installation something is wrong in general.

So my question is what could cause such a thing???

Answer (score 1):

You should verify root certificates inside the `cacerts` keystore. The file is stored in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` (or `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` in newer Java versions). As per [OpenJDK 10 Now Includes Root CA Certificates](https://dzone.com/articles/openjdk-10-now-includes-root-ca-certificates) post you can use `keytool` command to count them:

```
>jdk-10\bin\keytool -cacerts -list | find "Certificate" /c
Enter keystore password:  changeit
80
```

Most likely your Java installation is corrupted and you should reinstall. Do note that OpenJDK is provided by multiple vendors and it could be that you are using an installer which doesn't install the root certificates.

Comment: I downloaded it from open jdk directly also `keytool -cacerts -list | find "Zertifikat" /c` prints out 80

Comment: Then you have to manually verify which certificate in the trust chain for `google.de` is causing the problem and debug the problem.

Comment: @Alex: Are you using a shared Internet connection such as a business, school, or other organization? Run `keytool -printcert -sslserver google.de` to see exactly what cert chain you are getting, and what CA it uses. (_I_ get Google Internet Authority G3 under GlobalSign Root CA - R2.)

Comment: I just installed a new openjdk version and purged the last one... and still the same. I am on a home Internet connection. And this is what your command ouputs on my side https://pastebin.com/PJNU8nEE

Answer (score 0):

Ended up installing oracle jdk 10 (also 10.0.2) and that works

```
C:\Users\Alexander\Downloads>java "SSLPoke" google.de 443
Successfully connected
```